# Proof of finiteness of Selmer groups in Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, galois-cohomology

I'm trouble in understanding the proof of Lemma X.4.3 in Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves (2nd edition), that claims $H^1(G_{\bar{K}/K}, M; S)$ is finite.
In page 334, the book state the map
$$Hom(G_{L/K}, M; S) \rightarrow Hom(G_{\bar{K}/K}, M; S)$$
is an isomorphism. But I cannot understand why this is true.

The inflation-restriction sqeuence of Galois cohomology
$$0 \rightarrow Hom(G_{L/K}, M; S) \rightarrow Hom(G_{\bar{K}/K}, M; S) \rightarrow Hom(G_{\bar{K}/L}, M; S)$$
says if the above map is isomorphism then the image of the right map in the exact sequence is {0}.
This means the restrictions of $Hom(G_{\bar{K}/K}, M; S)$ to $G_{\bar{K}/L}$ is trivial map.
The book claims that this is true because $mM = 0$ and $G_{L/K}$ has exponent $m$.

If $\sigma \in (G_{\bar{K}/K})^m$ then $f(\sigma) = 0$ for all $f \in Hom(G_{\bar{K}/K}, M; S)$.
And $(G_{\bar{K}/K})^m \subset G_{\bar{K}/L}$.

But I cannot deduce the following, which is that I want to prove.

If $\sigma \in G_{\bar{K}/L}$ then $f(\sigma) = 0$ for all $f \in Hom(G_{\bar{K}/K}, M; S)$.

How can I prove the above fact?

Comment: That is because $L$ is the maximal abelian extension of $K$ of exponent $m$; homomorphisms $G_{\overline{K}/K}\to M$ factor through an abelian extension of $K$ so when you restrict them to $G_{\overline{K}/L}$ you are killing everything that has order $m$. It follows that the image of $f$ in $M$ must be $0$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm sorry that I cannot follow your explanation. What do you mean by homomorphisms factor through an abelian extension?

Comment: I meant through the Galois group of an abelian extension, because $M$ is a discrete abelian group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've straighten out this problem.
I appreciate Ferra's informative comments.

Let $f \in Hom(G_{\bar{K}/K},M;S)$ and $K_f$ the fixed field of $\ker(f)$.
Then $K_f$ is an abelian extension of $K$ having exponent $m$ that is unramified outside of $S$.

$\because$
$K_f$ is abelian because $M$ is abelian,

$K_f$ is unramified outside of $S$
because $f$ is trivial on inertia groups $I_v$ ($v \not\in S$),

and $K_f$ has exponent $m$ because $mM = 0$ so $G_{\bar{K}/K}^m \subset \ker(f)$.

Therefore, by the definition of $L$, $K_f \subset L$.
This means $f$ is trivial on $G_{\bar{K}/K}$, which is what I want to say.